# Is it possible to force mktime() to return a timestamp in UTC always?

Tags: c

Because the compiler the code will run on doesn't accept _mkgmtime and only mktime, I am forced to use mktime to convert broken down time to Unix TimeStamp and viceversa.

The old solution was to use _mkgmtime and gmtime to convert from broken down time to UNIX timestamp and viceversa. This worked until I tried to compile it and use it on my microcontroller.

Now, I have to somehow use mktime to generate UNIX timestamp from broken-down time and then to convert from broken-down time to UNIX timestamp. Both in UTC

Comment: Maybe set the time zone to UTC?

Comment: `mktime()` and `gmtime()` are standard library functions since C89.  I have no idea what `_mkgmtime()` is, but it looks like a Microsoftism.  One should always take care when engaging platform-specific features, due to their essential non-portability.

Comment: Bodo, how would I do that by just setting the small part of my code to UTC time zone? An example would be lovely, thank you.

Comment: See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72305183/how-to-convert-unix-time-stamps-utc-to-broken-down-time/72305539#comment128035542_72305539).

Comment: On a Posix system — which it sounds like yours is *not*, but anyway — the acepted way of setting the timezone is to call e.g. `putenv("TZ=UTC")`, then call `tzset()`.  (And if necessary you can fetch the old `TZ` value with `getenv` first, so you can set it back when your'e done.)  This is admittedly a kludge and a nuisance, and I suspect it won't work in your environment, but theoretically it's one option.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to force mktime() to return a timestamp in UTC always?

The C language specification says that the return value of `mktime()` is encoded the same way as that of `time()`, but it explicitly leaves that encoding unspecified.  Thus, the answer depends on the C implementation where your code will run.

On a POSIX system such as Linux, `time()` returns an integer number of seconds since the epoch, which is defined in terms of UTC, not local time.  Therefore, if your target machine is such a system then you don't need to do anything to get `mktime` to return a UTC timestamp.

HOWEVER, `mktime` assumes that its input is expressed in broken-down local time, and it will use the configured time zone (which is not included in the broken-down time) to perform the calculation. How the local time zone is configured is system dependent.